# Why is there 'no current induced' as the Earth travels around the Sun?

Tags: electromagnetism, estimation, solar-system

I have been reading a book on climate change which looks at various methods for generating electricity. One can induce a current by ensuring that a magnet appropriately 'cuts' through a magnetic field.

I do not understand why a current cannot be induced, at least in principle, as the earth naturally travels around the sun. Surely the sun's magnetic field is being 'cut' by a magnet and thus could generate electricity. Where is that 'potential energy' stored if this system does not generate any electricity?

Comment: The current induced by orbital motion circulates in the Earth’s magnetosphere.

Comment: Good question. But note that the Earth's magnetic field isn't very strong, and at this distance the Sun's magnetic flux density is about 1 nanotesla; Earth's field is about 32000 times stronger. FWIW, there's a cool animated graphic of the interaction between the Sun's & Earth's magnetic fields here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_magnetic_field#Magnetic_field_at_Earth_orbit

Comment: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope estimation?